# How to add criteria in a cross-tab query?

Tags: ms-access, crosstab, date-range

This is the model of table i am working with. Row names are departments, column names are the start date of week and data is the overtime used by those departments through that week.

[image]

What is happening right now is that my query is showing all the departments with all the week start dates available in the database. I want to give input for department as well as Date range, so that I don't have to look through whole data. 
Whenever i try to put `>=[Forms]![Home]![StartCalendar] and <=[Forms]![Home]![EndCalendar]` in criteria i get error

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine does not recognize '[Start d]' as a valid field name or expression.

I also want to be able to input department name so that I don't have to go through all the departments.
I hope you get the problem. Help! Please!

Comment: That won't work at all. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#Param

Comment: Declare custom function and then use that function as criteria. Can you share a sample file, so that we may have a try for you.